# Row_number() over with conditions in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have the query below, but,sometimes the `'code'` value is not available and then i have to use `'new_code'` instead.

My question is:  how can I change the query below to prioritize use of `code` but when its missing use `new_code` instead? is it possible?

```
with cte as (select *,
                        row_number() over (partition by code order by price) rn_low,
                        row_number() over (partition by code order by price DESC) rn_high
    from t
```

Comment: is code value become NULL?

Comment: If "code" and "new_code" have the same value (for different rows of course) should those get lumped together, or maintained separately?

Comment: "code" and "new_code" has not the same value, they are different but they are unique indentifiers of a machine.

Comment: @RahulBiswas yes" code becomes NULL, then I need to use new_code, thats my problem.

Comment: row_number() over (partition by COALESCE(code, new_code) you can use

Comment: @RahulBiswas i got the same result.  I need a way yo use code but when code is null, use new_code instead.